# EF CORE loads all data before any query takes place

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a console app to test EF Core with SQL Server Express edition. I have the following code in Program.cs

```
using EFCoreTutorials;
using EFCoreTutorials.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using (var context = new SalesManagementContext())
{
   
    var employees = context.Employees.ToList();

}
```

I wonder why context.Employees brings all data from my employees table without even asking for it with a query. If I have many tables in my database and my context class with a lot of data ,  are all these available from the context var at the beginning of program without even specifying which one of these I actuall want to use?

Thank you

Comment: Read documentation [Querying Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/)

Comment: The problem is that even before reaching line  var employees = context.Employees.ToList();  if I debug context it appears that in its results view has a list of all employees of database.

Comment: Debugging causes the query to run!

Comment: So you mean that var context = new SalesManagementContext()  loads all tables of the database referenced in class SalesManagementContext only if we are in debug mode ? And that does not happen when code runs without debugging ? It seems a bit weird.